# transferring from train arriving in Vienna to Vienna airport with more luggage then I can carry without a trolley

Tags: luggage, airports, airport-transfer, train-stations, vienna

Last time I arrived by train in Wien Hauptbahnhof with 3 airplane checked baggage sized bags (23 kg each), transferred to a local train to Vienna Airport (Flughafen Wien) train station, and there was a big problem: there where no trolleys at the train platform for luggage, and there was quite a large distance to walk from the train station to the terminal.

I thought an airport train station of a major European airport in a very developed country would have luggage trolleys at the platforms, but no, at least I didn't find them. And the train station wasn't even connected with the airport, had to walk outside quite a distance, at least 100 meters.

If I had 4 bags to check-in this would have been impossible. I can hardly believe I am the only person wanting to transfer from Vienna Airport train station to the airport with more luggage then I can carry. Even if they had wheels (not all of the bags have wheels), I have only 2 hands to pull bags, putting 2 of them on top of the other two and trying to roll on the wheels of the lower 2 bags has only a small chance of working without breaking the bag's wheels and the whole thing becoming un-steerable, because of the weight.

What are my options if I were to make this transfer next time with four bags?

Comment: When was the last time you flew from VIE? At least since 2012, the train station is directly connected to the main terminal hall through an underground tunnel.

Comment: In 2019. Maybe there was some construction going on and there was no tunnel passage. Anyway, tunnel or not, still moving four 23 kg checked bags thought the tunnel or even from one end of the terminal to another would be quite a challenge without a trolley.

Comment: There are actually two tunnels, so I'm afraid you must have missed them somehow. I never needed a trolley, so I can't answer your question, but there are trolleys everywhere in the airport and I've definitely seen lots of people pushing trolleys in the tunnel, so I would be somewhat surprised if there were none at the train station.

Comment: The lesson I learn from this is never to travel with more luggage than I can handle by myself, without trolleys.

Comment: I always thought you are not allowed to take more luggage in the train as you can carry...

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g Many train companies do have limits on the number/size/weight of luggage you can carry, either explicit (actual figures) or implicit (you must be able to carry it all yourself). They are a lot less publicised and enforced than those of airlines, but they often exist. However ÖBB does not seem to have any such limits, the only limitations I can find are on dangerous and illegal goods.

Comment: I am not sure I know any (airport) station in a “very developped country“ with trolleys on the platform. In Amsterdam or Paris there are signs and bollards explicitly preventing you from taking the airport trolleys to the train station. Main stations in Western European cities typically don't have them either and increasingly have automated gates you could not pass with four suitcases. The whole train system is designed around the assumption you are carrying less luggage than this (in some cases it's even forbidden).

Comment: ZRH has a actually luggage trolleys at the platform, that you can take in to the airport (and vv.). However i have never needed them, as I never travel with that much luggage.

Comment: To the OP: I actually can believe that you are indeed the only one that wants to take a train to an airport with more luggage than one can carry...

Comment: [Very closely related](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112720/what-technique-is-best-for-moving-two-large-23kg-suitcases-reasonably-short-d/112920#112920)

Comment: It should be noted, that you are only allowed to bring luggage on the trains of ÖBB, for instance, if your luggage can and will be stored in the luggage bins above or below your seat, or in designated luggage storage areas. As others will want to do the same, it is very unlikely that you will be allowed to bring more luggage than you can carry. Not, that it is not regularly done, though.

Answer (score 20):

Vienna International Airport offers porter services for departing and arriving passengers. The minimum charge is EUR 15, which covers porterage for up to five pieces of luggage. More details here: https://www.viennaairport.com/en/passengers/airport/baggage_services.

Comment: CAT also accepts luggage in Wien Mitte terminal, so you board the CAT with only cabin baggage.

Comment: @dlatikay what is CAT?

Comment: The [City Airport Train](https://www.cityairporttrain.com/en/home) linking the Wien Mitte public transport hub and VIE

Comment: I don't see how the CAT helps here, because you still have to get from the Hauptbahnhof to Wien Mitte, where the CAT is also a longish walk away via tunnel from the S-Bahn if I remember correctly, so same problem applies

Comment: Unfortunately, "as a result of worldwide flight restrictions and the suspension of many airlines, the operation of the City Airport Train will be temporarily suspended from March 19th, 2020. The City Check-In is not available until further notice." But worth keeping in mind for the future once it reopens.

Comment: Also note that the CAT terminal only accepts checked luggage from certain airlines (those within the Star Alliance, IIRC)

Comment: good answer for VIE itself, but doesn't help with the transfer at Vienna main station.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you cannot find an easy solution to your problem is that you are trying to do something that the system *intentionally* does not support.

Various sources on the Internet will claim that you are either allowed light hand luggage and one (!) piece of heavy luggage, or that you are allowed "what you can carry by yourself".

Interestingly, that information seems nowhere available on the ÖBB website. It should be in the "Beförderungsbedingungen", which also aren't easy to find, but if you dig, you can find them here:

https://www.oebb.at/static/tarife/de/handbuch_fuer_reisen_mit_der_oebb_in_oesterreich/index.html

check chapter A.4.1

There is actually no limit, except that what you bring must fit into the overhead compartment or under your seat (90 cm x 60 cm x 40 cm). No mention of number of items is made.

However, several places like the rules for disabled passengers (who get support getting into and out of the train, including carrying of **one** piece of luggage) clearly show that ÖBB does intend you to travel essentially as the Internet says, but without putting it into the rules. However, this implicit guideline explains why they don't help you in bringing more. (which they used to, in my childhood it was common to have trolleys at every slightly larger train station).

So you need to figure out how to do this by yourself, unless you want to hire a porter or transport service.

Some people tie luggage with 4 wheels to each other and form a small train. This seems to work reasonably well with 2 piece. YMMV.

For a short passage, like across a platform, asking a fellow traveller for help usually works, but few people will carry your stuff for more than a short distance. So check on which platforms your trains arrive and leave.

In VIE itself, the train station does exit into the main terminal, if you take the exit to the front of the arriving train. There are both elevators and a ramp, so you should be able to manage it with several pieces.

Comment: https://www.oebb.at/static/tarife/en/guide_for_travelling_abroad_with_oebb/Resources/pdf/3274427531.pdf states that "luggage must be easy to handle [...] and capable of being fitted into luggage spaces [...] must not inconvenience other passengers.". Even just getting off the train with that much luggage is going to inconvenience other passengers best I can tell. Recently was travelling with 3 *huge* suitcases/backpacks with two people (felt pretty bad about it) and made sure to call my railway company beforehand who assured me it was okay, but taking 4 big pieces of luggage with one person...